# Trouble with create_resources in Puppet 3.3.1

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant, puppet

I'm using puppet 3.3.1 to provision a vagrant box running ubuntu 12.04 with hiera.

I'm able to use hiera with `create_resources` when I declare every argument explicitly in my `yaml` file, but I can't get the defaults (optional 3rd argument to work) as described http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources

Here's an example of what isn't working:

```
# hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /vagrant/hiera
:hierarchy:
  - common
```

Here is the data in `common.yaml`

```
# common.yaml

ssh_keys:
  deployer_key:
    user: deployer
    # type: ssh-rsa
    # ensure: present
    key: "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA9Y9X..."
```

Now if I call the following in my manifest it will complain that no type has been passed to `ssh_authorized_key`.

```
create_resources("ssh_authorized_key", hiera("ssh_keys"), { ensure => present, type => "ssh-rsa" } )
```

But if I uncomment the type and ensure lines in `common.yaml` and call

```
create_resources("ssh_authorized_key", hiera("ssh_keys"))
```

everything works fine.

How do I get the defaults argument to work? It'd be nice not to DRY things up. I guess I can reuse parts in the yaml file itself with `&label` and `<<` syntax, but it seems like this default behavior should be possible.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it in a separate variable.

```
$defaults = {
    ensure => present,
    type => "ssh-rsa",
}

create_resources("ssh_authorized_key", hiera("ssh_keys"), $defaults)
```